# Join table with comma issue (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have a question, I want to join the table with comma, but if use normal method to join the table, it cannot get the correct data in the table. I am using MySQL 1.1.20 version. Below is my sample scenario:

I have two tables, table structure like below:

First Table name: **student**

```html
id   | name   | course_id
——————————————————————————
1      David     1,3 
2      Peter     2,4
3      Shawn     2,6
```

Second Table name: **subject**

```html
id    |    subject
———————————————————
1          English
2          Maths
3          Science
4          Geographic
5          Accounting
6          Art & Design
```

I want the actual result like below:

```html
id   | name | subject_name
——————————————————————————
1      David   English,Science
2      Peter   Maths,Geographic
3      Shawn   Maths,Art & Design
```

I have use below normal method to join two table, but I don't know how to join if got comma in the column.

```html
SELECT s.id as id,s.name as name,sub.subject as subject_name from student s left join subject sub on s.course_id = sub.id
```

Hope someone can guide me on how to solve this problem. Thanks.

MySql query browser version:

[image: img]

Comment: BTW 1.1.2 is not a MySQL version. The current versions are 8.x, the previous versions were 5.x.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks your comment. Can you provide sample to me to refer?

Comment: See the duplicate question link at the top of the page.

Comment: MySQL Query Browser is a query tool, it's not the database version.