# Find in set to get the separate values with comma

Tags: mysql, inner-join, find-in-set

Before I have asked the same problem ([Join table with comma issue (MySQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70358494/join-table-with-comma-issue-mysql)) about join table with comma in the column.

I have two tables, table structure like below:

First Table name: **student**

```html
id   | name   | course_id
——————————————————————————
1      David     1,3 
2      Peter     2,4
3      Shawn     2,6
```

Second Table name: **subject**

```html
id    |    subject
———————————————————
1          English
2          Maths
3          Science
4          Geographic
5          Accounting
6          Art & Design
```

I have tried this find_in_set method ([Search with comma-separated value mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208565/search-with-comma-separated-value-mysql)), but it cannot get the actual result. I want the actual result is like below:

```html
id   | name | subject_name
——————————————————————————
1      David   English,Science
2      Peter   Maths,Geographic
3      Shawn   Maths,Art & Design
```

I am using below code:

```html
SELECT student.id as id,student.name as name,student.subject as subject_name
FROM student
INNER JOIN subject
ON FIND_IN_SET(subject.id, student.course_id) > 0
```

But the result is shown me like below:

```html
id   | name | subject_name
——————————————————————————
1      David   English
2      David   Science
3      Peter   Maths
4      Peter   Geographic
5      Shawn   Maths
6      Shawn   Art & Design
```

Hope someone guide me on how to solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: *I am using below code* You went the right way, but stopped halfway. Add GROUP BY and GROUP_CONCAT().

Comment: @Akina Thanks for your comment. Can you show me sample how to add group by and group_concat() based on my question?

Comment: @ProGu have done this already.

Comment: Ok. Now the problem cannot show value with comma like "1      David   English,Science"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this

```
SELECT student.id as id, student.name as name, GROUP_CONCAT(subject.subject) as subject_name
FROM student
INNER JOIN subject
ON FIND_IN_SET(subject.id, student.course_id) > 0
GROUP BY student.id, student.name
```

Usually we don't concat everything in SQL query, but you can do

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', student.id, student.name, GROUP_CONCAT(subject.subject)) as concated_value
FROM student
INNER JOIN subject
ON FIND_IN_SET(subject.id, student.course_id) > 0
GROUP BY student.id, student.name
```

Comment: Thanks. But how to show value with comma like "1      David   English,Science"

Comment: @DavidHolly ??? your tell *I want the actual result is like below* - and the 1st query gives such output precisely.

Comment: To preserve the order of the subjects you want (untested) `GROUP_CONCAT(subject.subject ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(subject.id, student.course_id))`